# The service is not responding to the control function

Tags: windows, windows-services, python-3.6

I am trying to use the reference (http://ryrobes.com/python/running-python-scripts-as-a-windows-service/) to create a service using python 3.6, but I am get this error

> NET HELPMSG 2186
>
> The service is not responding to the control function.

While I try to start from `services.msc`, the error is

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Can anyone help?

Thanks
-Megha

Comment: Was this fixed for you?

Comment: Yes. I have to add the path to python and dependent libraries path to PATH variable.